# In edit mode Id in the url disappears in button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code

```
if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
{
}
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "ReportManager", new { id = model.ReportID });
```

This code is invoked when save button is clicked in edit page. Now when i remove values from a textbox in edit page and click save, The id in the url is being removed. Any suggestions on what should I do.

My view

```
@{ string Reporturl = "";
    if (Model != null)
    {
         if (Model.ReportURL != null)
         {
               Reporturl = Model.ReportID + "_ID_" + Model.ReportURL.Replace(@"/", "");
         }
    }
@Html.Label("Report URL: " + @Reporturl);
    }
```

Submit Part

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="btn_wrap">
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn1" />
             @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "List", "ReportManager", null, new { @class = "btn1" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the text box which am clearing during edit

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReportID)
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReportName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReportName)
<div class="clearfix"></div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReportName, new { maxlength = 50, style = "width:100%" })
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your razor view as well?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I can't see any form or submit button here.

Comment: What textbox? What button? Which view have you shown us (the one your editing or the one your redirect to)? What is the `ID` in the url your referring to? And what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Now I have added everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and my problem was solved

```
RedirectToAction("Edit", "ReportManager", new { ReportId = model.ReportID });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Return View instead of return RedirectToAction like below.

```
return View("Edit", model);
```

Comment: I did this . Before doing this my url was "ReportManager/Edit?ReportId=1" But now it is  "ReportManager/Edit" . I need my url to be "ReportManager/Edit?ReportId=1"